# Filter or Check Date in A Date Range

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, for-loop

It's totally a simple or basic requirement. I am trying to get a date from a list of date using `C#`. So what I've done, made a function and iterated that with a `for` loop. I've tried to make the list function into two ranges and passed the value from the `DatePicker` control as follows:

```
private void btnClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime theFromDate = dateTimePicker1.Value;
    DateTime theToDate = dateTimePicker2.Value;

    List<DateRange> lstRange = GetDateRange();

    /**Trying To Get The Date From The Range - Starts**/
    var dates = new List<DateTime>();

    for (var dt = theFromDate; dt <= theToDate; dt = dt.AddDays(1))
    {
        dates.Add(dt);
        //MessageBox.Show(dt.Date.ToString());
    }

    List<DateRange> lst = GetDateRange();
    foreach(var item in lst)
    {
        if(theFromDate <= item.EndtDate.Date)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(theFromDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") + " in the date range!");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(theFromDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") + " not in the date range!");
        }
    }
    /**Trying To Get The Date From The Range - Ends**/
}
public class DateRange
{
    public DateTime date { set; get; }
    public DateTime EndtDate { set; get; }
}

/**List of Dates Here - Starts**/
public List<DateRange> GetDateRange()
{
    List<DateRange> lstDate = new List<DateRange>();

    DateRange aDateRange = new DateRange();
    aDateRange.StartDate = Convert.ToDateTime("10-Aug-2018");
    aDateRange.EndtDate = Convert.ToDateTime("13-Aug-2018");
    lstDate.Add(aDateRange);

    return lstDate;
}
/**List of Dates Here - Ends**/
```

Unfortunately this doesn't return the desired output though the list has the specific date.

**Update 1:**
**Expected Output** - `FromDate` and `ToDate` values are stored in the list.

```
 FromDate      ToDate 
 10-AUG-2018   13-AUG-2018

 **in the date range**

 FromDate      ToDate 
 13-AUG-2018   16-AUG-2018

 **in the date range** //As 13 is the end date in the given list

 FromDate      ToDate 
 8-AUG-2018    10-AUG-2018

 **in the date range** //As 10 is the start date in the given list

 FromDate      ToDate 
 8-AUG-2018    8-AUG-2018

 **not in the date range** //As 10 is the start date in the given list
```

Comment: Your code is confusing. Try to explain what you want to achieve, add an exanple input and the redpective desired output. What is the purpose of overwriting the `aDateRange.date` three times, and with constant before adding the last one to the list? Your `GetDateRange` will return the same list of a single instance of `DateRange` whaterer that is.

Comment: Please see the updated post @ZorgoZ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out what it is you're trying to do, to be perfectly honest, and I can't help but feel you're "over-engineering" your solution.

First, a "date range" is just two dates - a staring date and an end date, but your `GetDateRange` method has 4 dates inside it, which it returns as a list. This is incredibly confusing - and I'm not sure if you're trying to get multiple date-ranges (multiple pairs) or a single date-range out of it. **Given that all the dates are one after another, I'm going to assume the latter.**

```
public class DateRange
{
  public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
  public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}

public DateRange GetStaticDateRange()
{
  //It seems counterproductive to add all 4 dates here, 
  //given that these are all one after the other
  return new DateRange
  { 
    StartDate = new DateTime(2018, 7, 10),
    EndDate = new DateTime(2018, 7, 13) 
  };
  //Obviously this can be modified as needed to return whatever combination of 
  //start-end dates you want, but this method will only ever return ONE range
  //However, this method could just as well accept parameters and / or access other resources
}

public bool IsInDateRange(DateTime dateToCheck, DateRange targetRange)
{
  //An argument can be made to use non-encompassing comparisons for both checks
  //depending on your requirements
  return dateToCheck >= targetRange.StartDate && dateToCheck <= targetRange.EndDate;
}
```

The above has a simple class for storing a "date-range" (aptly called `DateRange`), and a sample method which checks if a given `DateTime` is valid inside a specific `DateRange`.

EDIT:
OK, so from your updated question it seems like you're trying to find if two date-ranges overlap (at all).

In which case, the code below should help.

```
public static bool DateRangesOverlap(DateRange range1, DateRange range2)
{
  return (range1.StartDate >= range2.StartDate && range1.StartDate <= range2.EndDate) || 
         (range1.EndDate >= range2.StartDate && range1.EndDate <= range2.EndDate);
}
```

Here's a working example on [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/V2tQL0) with your test cases. Note that I'm still using the `DateRange` class as defined above with a constructor added for brevity.

Also please note that the `DateRange` class has no sanity-check for the start and end parameters, and it's possible to create a `DateRange` with the two values reversed (i.e. start > end) which, obviously, would cause errors. But this is just an example so implementations of these things I leave to you. ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and if you have time, please see the updated post @Shaamaan.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few bugs in your code. 
For example in the GetDateRange(), you are adding only one date to the range, and its date will set to 13-Aug-2018, so that is one thing you need to fix, and if your goal is to find a date in a range of dates, you can use Linq. To compare ranges, I also suggest use DateTime.CompareTo Method. See the code below for corrections of your errors:

```
    public static bool RangeContainsDate(DateTime queriedDateTime)
        {
            var queriedDateRange = new DateRange { Date = queriedDateTime };
            List<DateRange> dates = GetDateRange();
            return dates.Where(d => d.CompareTo(queriedDateRange) == 0).Any();
        }

        /**List of Dates Here - Starts**/
        public static List<DateRange> GetDateRange()
        {
            List<DateRange> lstDate = new List<DateRange>();

            DateRange aDateRange1 = new DateRange();
            aDateRange1.Date = Convert.ToDateTime("10-Aug-2018");
            lstDate.Add(aDateRange1);

            DateRange aDateRange2 = new DateRange();
            aDateRange2.Date = Convert.ToDateTime("11-Aug-2018");
            lstDate.Add(aDateRange2);

            DateRange aDateRange3 = new DateRange();
            aDateRange3.Date = Convert.ToDateTime("12-Aug-2018");
            lstDate.Add(aDateRange3);

            DateRange aDateRange4 = new DateRange();
            aDateRange4.Date = Convert.ToDateTime("13-Aug-2018");
            lstDate.Add(aDateRange4);

            return lstDate;
        }
    }
}

public class DateRange : IComparable<DateRange>
{
    public DateTime Date { set; get; }

    public int CompareTo(DateRange other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(other, null))
        {
            return -1;
        }
        return DateTime.Compare(Date, other.Date);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and if you have time, please see the updated post @PiJei.

Answer (score 1):

```
    private void btnClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //DateTime theFromDate = dateTimePicker1.Value;
        DateTime theToDate = dateTimePicker2.Value;

        List<DateRange> lstRange1 = GetDateRange();
        List<DateRange> lstRange2 = GetDateRange();

        var result = lstRange1.Any(x => x.date >= theToDate && lstRange2.Any(y => y.date < theToDate));

        if (result)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(theToDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") + " in the date range!");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(theToDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") + " not in the date range!");
        }
    }



    public List<DateRange> GetDateRange()
    {
        List<DateRange> lstDate = new List<DateRange>();

        lstDate.Add(new DateRange { date = Convert.ToDateTime("10-Aug-2018") });
        lstDate.Add(new DateRange { date = Convert.ToDateTime("11-Aug-2018") });
        lstDate.Add(new DateRange { date = Convert.ToDateTime("12-Aug-2018") });
        lstDate.Add(new DateRange { date = Convert.ToDateTime("13-Aug-2018") });

        return lstDate;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and if you have time, please see the updated post @Valeh Mikayilzadeh.